# How should I implement a very simple one-to-one chat on a PHP page? Comet?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, comet

How should I implement a very simple one-to-one chat on a PHP page? I thought I should use Ajax and jQuery, but this generates too many connections to the server.

I know that Facebook is using Comet, but after searching I only found one article from 2009. Now it’s 2011, and there are still very few articles about Comet.

Why? What is better? Is there a good article about creating a very simple one-to-one chat application?

Comment: good job giving the question life @Paul

Comment: @JanDragsbaek: hopefully when I’m writing programming questions in Chinese, someone will do the same for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use websockets, for example via [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/). If you use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on the frontend, it will work in almost any browser.